# Parsing a semicolon-separated list

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, csv

I have a semicolon-separated list of values, for example:

```
strins s = "param1=true;param2=4;param3=2.0f;param4=sometext;";
```

I need a functions:

```
public bool ExtractBool(string parameterName, string @params);
public int ExtractInt(string parameterName, string @params);
public float ExtractFloat(string parameterName, string @params);
public string ExtractString(string parameterName, string @params);
```

Is there a special functions in .net that can help me with semicolon-separated list ?

PS: parameter names are equal within a list.

Comment: Your list is semicolon-separated, not comma-separated. Also, what happens if one of the values needs to contain the separator?

Comment: Sorry, my bad english. I will fix it.

Comment: will param1 always be a bool and param2 always an int and so on? Or can they all be any type? Also, can you have a `;` in your strings?

Comment: what happens if one of the values needs to contain the separator? ->>>nothing happens. it doesn't have any recursion or something like this.||||||||||||||||||||||will param1 always be a bool and param2 always an int and so on? Or can they all be any type? ->>> No, it's just an example. I have a semicolon-separated list and parameter name. I know exactly a parameter name and it's type. And I know it is in list. I only need to find its value.

Answer (score 3):

As a starting point, what you need is the String.Split() method - it will split your string into a string array.

You'll find loads of examples of this all over the web.

Answer (score 3):

For string better you can use `Split(';');`

You can try this for split comma

```
string s ="param1=true;param2=4;param3=2.0f;param4=sometext;";

string[] sArray = s.Split(';')
```

Comment: I think that you mean: string[] sArray = s.Split(';');

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better way to do this and avoid having a whole bunch of empty array elements:

```
        string lsToString = "Your String Here";
        string[] laChars = { "," };
        string[] laTo = lsToString.Split(laChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Makes it much easier to work with after you split the string because you don't have to worry about empty elements.

Pete

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same so I could extract name value pairs from an azure connection string.

The only slight difference witrh the implementation is the overload in splitting the parameters on the equals where we are using the overload to ensure we only get two results.

This means that when a paramter value contains '=' characters then they will be ignored.
I.e. it will still work on a value such as 'AccountKey=ABCDEFGHI==;'

Hopefully this saves someone a few minutes!

```
public class StorageConfiguration
{
    public string StorageAccountConnectionString { get; set; }

    public StorageConfiguration(string storageAccountConnectionString)
    {
        StorageAccountConnectionString = storageAccountConnectionString;
    }

    public string GetConnectionStringItem(ConnectionStringItem connectionStringItem)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StorageAccountConnectionString)) throw new ArgumentException("StorageAccountConnectionString is empty");

        var items = StorageAccountConnectionString.Split(";", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToDictionary(x=> x.Split("=", 2)[0], y=> y.Split("=", 2)[1]);

        return items[connectionStringItem.ToString()];
    }


    public enum ConnectionStringItem
    {
        DefaultEndpointsProtocol,
        BlobEndpoint,
        AccountName,
        AccountKey
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `ToDictionary` is confusing here. It's recreated and dismissed for every method call. If caching the dictionary is not desired I would do something like `return ...Select(x => x.Split("=", 2)).Where(x => x[0] == connectionStringItem_AsString).Select(x => x[1]);`